how to store username and password as environment variable from credentials manager in jenkins
I have been trying to store the username environment variable name and password as value.
I'm fetching username and password from credential manager. Below is the script which I tired to work with but it didn't work.
environment{

My_CRED=credentials('MY_CREDENTIALS')

}

but this stores the environment variable in below form.
My_CRED_USR= MYUSERNAME
My_CRED_PSW=****
but I wanted to store environment variable in the form of
MYUSERNAME=****
Please help me with script.

There are other ways to handle credentials (more info here).
What you want can be done via the withCredentials(...) method; Example:
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'MY_CREDENTIALS', passwordVariable: 'MYPASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'MYUSERNAME')]) { ... code... }
